# ESD diodes - on what lines?

Tags: diodes, circuit-protection, esd

I'm just learning about the use of ESD diodes to protect your system.

Although I've read multiple cases on this being more a black box magic than true science, I'm still going to try.

On what 'signals' or 'traces' from my PCB would it be wise to place some diodes? I do not mean a specific PCB but more 'in general.' What's a rule of thumb? Incoming power lines? Only RX/TX pins or all I/O pins?

Also, I have an example as such which is for an isolated connector. Would it make sense to place such a ESD protection on here? Why? Why not? -> My mind says it is isolated so would be rather safe already.

[image]

Comment: It's not black box magic. It may just seem like it. The rule of thumb is that you should protect lines from ESD, if it is sensitive to ESD. For example if it goes directly to a chip that cannot handle much ESD like a small MCU, but for example many chips meant to interface with external devices (e.g. RS485 tranceivers) have quite strong ESD protection built-in so they do not necessarily need extra protection, unless you are going to use it in an application which encounters a lot of ESD. I also don't see how that conenctor is isolated, it has connections to ground and supplies.

Comment: In general on all lines that go to the outer world. ESD can also happen between copper traces if they are close enough, so make sure your protection is as close to connectors as possible.

Comment: *being more a black box magic than true science* That says more about the authors of the articles and their knowledge of ESD than anything else. In chip design ESD is a big issue and getting it wrong can cost lots of money so this field is definitely not black magic to those that are responsible (which is me, sometimes).

Comment: *Isolated connector*, the cable that is connected to that connector could have a charge (or your PCB can be charged and discharge through the cable) so basically all pins need ESD protection. You can often safely skip ESD protection on supply pins as there are usually decoupling capacitors between supplies that absorb the ESD pulse.